# Failed to read master_preferences file - Watir

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

Get this error when trying to drive chrome with watirs web driver ..... ie works fine.

```
C:\Users\rallen26346>irb
irb(main):001:0> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true
irb(main):003:0> browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
Started ChromeDriver
port=9515
version=26.0.1383.0
log=C:\Users\rallen26346\chromedriver.log
[4636:5120:0122/113039:ERROR:master_preferences.cc(104)] Failed to read master_preferences file at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\master_p
references. Falling back to default preferences.
[4636:5120:0122/113039:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(91)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.
[4636:5120:0122/113039:ERROR:bluetooth_adapter_win.cc(23)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x..fb028c9b0 url="about:blank" title="about:blank">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Comment: They did actually do this - see line 3 of the irb session.

Comment: I tried editing the question to remove that irrelevant section because it fooled me, too. Guess the question writer hasn't gotten around to accepting my edit, yet.

Comment: @JustinKo: Thanks, I guess I did not read the rest of the question when I saw the first error. :)

Comment: @AbeHeward: I have edited the question to remove unnecessary code that confused me.